# I cannot see newly uploaded products in "Manage Products" in the admin

Tags: product, products-management, csv

I uploaded around 100 new products by CSV but cannot see them in "Manage Products" in the admin (having no filters on the search). Strangely I can see them in the tables in the database and when I look at a category can also see them in "Products in Category". I have flushed the cache and reindexed the products.

I have used this technique many times before so it is quite baffling. I cannot find anything out there with these symptoms of this problem. Thanks to anyone that has either previously had this problem or can shed some light - suggestions, etc damn I'll take anything. Thanks.

Comment: when you import product using csv then make sure you set store view and status

Comment: Did do - thanks though. Any more?

Comment: Must check product visibilty

Comment: How are you uploading the products? By using an extension or default magento product upload?

Comment: @Keyul Shah - I cannot find the products in "Manage Products" in the admin so I cannot.

Comment: @Sukeshini - default magento product upload by CSV

Comment: hmm no idea boss can you please update your question via with csv

Comment: @Keyul Shah - it's already there - "I uploaded around 100 new products by CSV" - first line

Comment: update the csv code I mean

Comment: Go to database and check `catalog_product_entity` table. Check whether does it contains products which you uploaded

Comment: @Sukeshini - Yes I can see the newly uploaded products there - still not in the admin, manage products section though

Answer (score 1):

The sql select that is executed when viewing the product grid is this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '273') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '526') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
```

The attribute ids may be different depending on your instance, but the idea is that the main table (`catalog_product_entity`) is `INNER JOIN`-ed with the `catalog_product_entity_int` twice. Once for showing the status and once for showing the visibility.
If you don't have values in the `catalog_product_entity_int` for `status` and `visibility` for some products they won't appear in the grid.
But you can still edit the product. Just click on any edit link and then change the id in the url to the one you need.  If click save on it you will be able to see that on the grid.

I guess you cannot do that for 100 products manually.
but you can run this script that will automatically add status and visibility to the imported products.
Identify the product ids that are missing in the grid but they are present in the `catalog_product_entity` table and put them all in an array. Let's call that `$productIds`.
Then run this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($productIds),
    array('status'=>1, 'visibility'=>4),
    0
);
```

This should solve your issue.
If you modified the default grid and added your own attributes then you might need to add them in this script also.
Try it first for one product and see if it works.